# Visual Assist X -- More items in Intellisense?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, intellisense, visual-assist

Right now, Visual Assist X shows 5 items in my Intellisense suggestions window (i.e. when I begin typing).

Is there any way to increase it? 5 items is too few. :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried resizing the window?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the window is re-sizable. Mine is currently showing 10 entries (looks like the maximum), but I could make it smaller.

Comment: Mine used to be 10, but when I updated to the latest version it sorta got decreased...

Comment: I'm using 10.6.1856.0 from August. Did you install the newer one from Oct 2?

Comment: Yeah I'm using the one from October 2. Also, I think it depends on the context -- if you begin typing `::`, for example, it shows all the entries. But if you begin typing an identifier, then it only shows like 5.

Comment: I just upgraded to the October build. No change in how it is working for me (Visual Studio 2008).

Comment: Weird, it give me only 3 choices. :\

Comment: In VS2008, it is still resizable, with a wider range. In VS2010, not resizable, but showing 9.

Comment: I'm using VS2008. Yes, it's indeed resizable, but only temporarily -- it still gives me 5 choices even when I expand it to like 30.